# How to deal with Pension as a postdoc regularly moving country?

Tags: funding, international

I am a postdoc from the UK that currently lives in France paid by a Canadian institution as a contractor (not employee). I move country roughly every 1-2 years. How do I get a pension for old age? UK pension funds won't accept people living abroad and my employers do not pay into pensions.

Comment: This is more of a workplace issue than an academic one.

Comment: Related: [How to take care of pension funds if career is spread over many different countries?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/20383/73033) on Money.SE.

Comment: Get a more permanent position, or start saving for yourself.

Comment: @JonCuster As the meme says, one does not simply get a more permanent position. Basically every postdoc is already trying to do that, not only for their pension.

Comment: One does not simply get the position they want. The want of a pension may well change what position is acceptable, whether in academia, national lab, or industry.

Comment: When I was in Canada, my postdoc supervisor told me: your first job is to find a permanent position; your second job is to work for me.

Comment: @Buffy I'd argue it's more of a finance issue than a workplace issue.  Pensioners don't normally have a workplace :)